# Python Cointoss output wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the coin toss script i wrote in python 3

```
import random

def tosscoin():
    numbers = input("Times to flip coin: ")
    recordList = ['Heads', 'Tails']
    heads = 0
    tails = 0
    for number in numbers:
        flip = random.randint(0, 1)
        if (flip == 0):
            print("Heads")
            recordList.append('Heads')
        else:
            print("Tails")
            recordList.append('Tails')
            print(str(recordList))
            print(str(recordList.count('Heads')) + str(recordList.count('Tails')))

print(tosscoin())
```

and my input was 10

the output i got was

```
Tails
['Heads', 'Tails', 'Tails']
12
Tails
['Heads', 'Tails', 'Tails', 'Tails']
13
None
```

Process finished with exit code 0

why does the output come out this way ?

Comment: what output did you want?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `for number in numbers` do `for number in range(int(numbers))`

Reason is the result of `input` is a string, not a number. So if you want to do it 10 times, you need to first parse to `int` then iterate for that many steps

Answer (score 0):

The modified code is as follows:

```
import random

def tosscoin():
    numbers = int(input("Times to flip coin: "))
    recordList = []
    heads = 0
    tails = 0
    for number in range(numbers):
        flip = random.randint(0, 1)
        # print(flip)
        if (flip == 0):
            print("Heads")
            recordList.append('Heads')
        else:
            print("Tails")
            recordList.append('Tails')
            
        print(recordList)
        print(recordList.count('Heads') + recordList.count('Tails'))
    
    return recordList

print(tosscoin())
```

The output is:

```
Times to flip coin:  10

Heads
['Heads']
1
Heads
['Heads', 'Heads']
2
Tails
['Heads', 'Heads', 'Tails']
3
Tails
['Heads', 'Heads', 'Tails', 'Tails']
4
Heads
['Heads', 'Heads', 'Tails', 'Tails', 'Heads']
5
Tails
['Heads', 'Heads', 'Tails', 'Tails', 'Heads', 'Tails']
6
Heads
['Heads', 'Heads', 'Tails', 'Tails', 'Heads', 'Tails', 'Heads']
7
Heads
['Heads', 'Heads', 'Tails', 'Tails', 'Heads', 'Tails', 'Heads', 'Heads']
8
Heads
['Heads', 'Heads', 'Tails', 'Tails', 'Heads', 'Tails', 'Heads', 'Heads', 'Heads']
9
Tails
['Heads', 'Heads', 'Tails', 'Tails', 'Heads', 'Tails', 'Heads', 'Heads', 'Heads', 'Tails']
10
['Heads', 'Heads', 'Tails', 'Tails', 'Heads', 'Tails', 'Heads', 'Heads', 'Heads', 'Tails']
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of issues here:

- `recordList` isn't initialized as an empty list, so you're actually counting 1 too many "Tails" and 1 too many "Heads"
- the indentation isn't correct so you are printing `recordList` and
  the heads & tails counts each time the coin toss result is "Tails"
- the `input` function returns a string. Therefore, your `for` loop is
  looping over the **characters** of your input. So if your input is
  "10", there will be 2 iterations because there are 2 characters in
  "10". You first need to convert the input to an integer and use the `range` function to loop as many times as needed
- `print(tosscoin())` displays `None` because the `tosscoin` function
  doesn't return any value

Here is a code that should work as you're expecting:

```
import random

def tosscoin():
    numbers = int(input("Times to flip coin: "))
    recordList = []
    for number in range(numbers):
        flip = random.randint(0, 1)
        if (flip == 0):
            print("Heads")
            recordList.append('Heads')
        else:
            print("Tails")
            recordList.append('Tails')
    print(str(recordList))
    print(str(recordList.count('Heads')) + " " + str(recordList.count('Tails')))

tosscoin()
```

Answer (score 0):

there are several thing to unpack here

first: `numbers = input("Times to flip coin: ")` the result of `input` is a string so `numbers` is a string, if you input 10 that is the string "10" and when you do `for number in numbers:` you iterate over the character inside it, and there is only two characters in "10" so you get only 2 iterations

second: block code in python, as you should know, are base in indentation so you only get to print your `recordList` whenever you get a tail, and just so happens that in that occasion you randomly got two tail in a row

third: here in `print(str(recordList.count('Heads')) + str(recordList.count('Tails')))` you're adding two string, the `+` with strings is concatenation, in this occasion you got 2 tail in a row, so your heads count is 1 because you have your record list starting with one heads and tail inside from `recordList = ['Heads', 'Tails']` and your tail count is 2, the one you just append it and the one that was inside it from before in the first loop and 3 in the second, so that is where your 12 and 13 come from

finally here `print(tosscoin())` you print the result of the `tosscoin` function, but that function does not return any value, when any function in python finalize working if there isn't any return statement it will return None, and that is where the `None` come from

Some simple solution are:

- make your input into a number by calling `int` on it
- use the range function to get the desire number of iterations
- you declare the variables `heads` and `tail` but don't use it and instead use the `recordList`, if you want the list start it empty so you have the correct values and remove the previous two, or use them alongside, you can also add a return value to this function, lets said for example this recordList

.

```
import random

def tosscoin():
    numbers = int(input("Times to flip coin: "))
    recordList = []
    heads = 0
    tails = 0
    for n in range(numbers):
        flip = random.randint(0, 1)
        if flip == 0 :
            heads += 1
            recordList.append("Heads") 
            print("Heads",heads)
        else:
            tails += 1
            recordList.append("Tails")
            print("Tails",tails)
        #print(recordList) #uncomment this if you want to print the list in each iteration
    return recordList

print(tosscoin())
```